# Cannot load DLL or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, c++, windows

On my dev machine everything works fine. On my test machine I can't run my .exe because it says "Lib.dll or one of its dependencies was not found". However Lib.dll is in the same directory as the .exe and I ran CorFlags against both the DLL and the EXE: both of them report "PE32" so they are both 32 bit. The Lib.dll doesn't have any other dependencies. I removed all of them and tested. Why else might it be failing?

Comment: Use *dependency walker* on the failing machine. Also, look at the *fusion bind logs*.

Comment: Can you try running a dependency checker? VS used to have depends.exe, and I see, e.g., http://www.dependencywalker.com/ out there that looks basically the same.

Comment: You horrible mangled the error message, it is of course **or one of** its dependencies was not found.

Comment: @HansPassant You're right. I used dependency walker. It says MSVCR110D.DLL and MSVCP100D.DLL are missing. I don't know why though. I installed the 2012, 2010, and 2005 VC++ redistributable. Ugh.

edit: going to try in release mode and report back.

Comment: Only ever deploy the Release build of your project.  You can't easily get the debug versions of these DLLs installed on another machine.  Nor would you want to.

Comment: @HansPassant I apologize to Visual Studio for all of my bad mouthing. Release mode worked fine. Thank you for your help. Do you know of any good solutions for packaging. E.g. I want an .msi to deploy this thing.

Comment: @KyleM You can easily create an installer by right clicking on the project, Properties, then select Publish tab. Go through the Publish Wizard, you can end up an installer by a few clicks.

Comment: @CsabaToth I did that earlier, I ended up with an installer and a bunch of files. I want an all in one installer so I'm going with the InstallShield LE that comes with VS 2012.

Comment: @KyleM Oh, I see you want an msi. Yes, the wizard won't generate an msi installer, but it's more than nothing. I'd consider WiX.

Comment: @CsabaToth Thanks, I did it with InstallShield instead, and made a bootstrapping .exe that runs all the required installers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [dependencywalker](http://dependencywalker.com) as someone suggested in the comments. Dependencywalker showed that I had a couple missing DLLs that I traced back to belonging to the Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable. So make sure you have the correct version of Visual C++ Redistributable installed on your testing/production machines. I also switched the project in Visual Studio from Debug to Release mode, a mistake I've also made in the past, so I won't be making that mistake again anytime soon. If you leave your project in Debug mode, the DLL dependencies are slightly different than if you put it into release mode. Visual C++ redistributable does not have the Debug DLLs present, only the Release ones - so even if you are testing, this change might be necessary unless you know where to find the Debug DLLs (which are installed with Visual Studio on your development machine).